# Is it possible to use the built-in Everyone group as a security group with AAD DS for a VM attached to a domain?

Tags: azure, microsoft-office-365, entra-domain-services, office365

Is it possible to use the built-in O365 Everyone group as a security group with AAD DS for a VM attached to a domain?

I assume it's not possible to use the built-in O365 groups as security groups, but I thought I would double-check in case someone has figured out a way to do this. They don't actually show up in the AD DS "groups" list at all, so I'm guessing they can't be treated as "security" groups and used to apply RDP permissions on an Azure VM joined to an Azure AD DS domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct.  There is an option with Azure AD Premium P1 however to add an "all users" security group.  I would expect you would see that as it's created as an actual security group in the directory.  This group, however, also includes guest users (it's quite literally all users in the directory).

That being said if you have premium license - you can use a dynamic group to create your own group that contains only your domain users.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic group"? Is there a way to make it add a new user automatically when the new user is added to O365? (Currently I'm just using a regular "security group" in AAD DS, so new users would need to be manually added.)